# What is an idiomatic way of checking props (or state) before dispatching an action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

In one of my React components, I'm using `componentWillMount()` to call a function I passed in as a prop via `react-redux`. This function dispatches an action that `redux-saga` listens on to load search filters for a form.

Now that I'm using `redux-persist` and the state rehydrates automatically, I would like to check if these search filters exist and were hydrated before calling my function. There's not much point in dispatching an action to retrieve data that's already in state and ready to use.

What is an idiomatic way to do this? Should I just check the array length on each prop in an `if` statement and only call the function if they exist already? Or should I be leveraging `redux-saga` anyway?

**Edit**: Writing business logic inside the Action Creator seems like an anti-pattern, but it's an option. Also, writing custom Redux Middleware is also an option. Will investigate both and leave an answer if necessary.

**Edit 2**: I'm not going to answer my own question, because the solution I found doesn't strictly relate to this question. I discovered [redux-logic](https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic) and it's been perfect for my use case.

Comment: Shouldn't your reducer just ignore the action?

Comment: @sean Fantastic! Thanks for sharing about redux-logic, it helps to get the word out. If I can answer any questions regarding it just let me know.